# SVG hover animation glitch issue

Tags: animation, svg, visual-glitch

I'm trying to activate this animation on hover which is working! but it's glitchy every-time the mouse is moved it fires again. Is there a solution to this issue? also is there a way to force the animation to finish after mouseout?

```
<svg id="squid" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="180px" height="192.8px" viewBox="0 0 130 225"
     xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMax meet">
<defs>
</defs>
<g class="squid">
<path id="left-arm" class="left-arm" d="M6,20.8c0,0,21.3,0,21.3,21.2c0,21.2-20.8,18.4-20.8,41.4c0,22.6,36.7,34.4,52.9-8.9"/>
<path id="right-arm" class="right-arm" d="M122,20.8c0,0-21.3,0-21.3,21.2c0,21.2,20.8,18.4,20.8,41.4c0,22.6-36.7,34.4-52.8-8.9"/>
<path id="lightning" class="lightning" d="M65.2,43.7L67.7,56l3.1,15.9L63.4,56L52.9,33.2l9.9-0.4l-5-27.6l17.3,38L65.2,43.7z"/>
<path id="left-mid-arm" class="left-mid-arm" d="M58.5,99.6c-31.1,25.5-50,28.7-50,50.8c0,15.8,10.2,22.9,16,26.6"/>
<path id="right-mid-arm" class="right-mid-arm" d="M69.7,99.6c31.1,25.5,50,28.7,50,50.8c0,15.8-10.2,22.9-16,26.6"/>
    <g id="right-limb">
        <path id="right-leg" class="right-leg" d="M63.2,107.6c0,0,6.3-0.1,10.3,7.6c1.6,3.1,2.4,6.4,2.3,10.2c-0.1,2.7-0.6,6.1-0.6,6.1"/>
        <path id="right-foot" class="right-foot" d="M51.5,156.9c-2.3,3-3.7,6.7-3.7,11.9c0,5.1,1.4,8.8,3.1,11.5"/>
    </g>
<path id="left-leg" class="left-leg" d="M63.8,107.6c0,0-14.3,0.3-11.6,20.6c2.8,20.8,27.9,19,27.9,40.6c0,14.6-11.2,18-11.2,18"/>
<g class="body">
    <path id="body" d="M84.7,62.6c0.1-0.1,5.1-1.5,5-5.1V5c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5h-42c-2.8,0-5,2.2-5,5v52.4c0,2.4,1.7,4.4,3.9,4.9
    c0.2,0,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.3c2,0.8,3.5,2.7,3.5,5c0,2.2-1.4,4.1-3.3,4.9c-0.1,0.1-5.4,1.2-5.3,5.3v0.4c0,2.8,2.2,5,5,5h1.5
    c2.2,0,7.3,2.2,8.6,4.2c-1.1,1.9-1.7,4-1.7,6.4c0,6.9,5.6,12.5,12.5,12.5S76,100.6,76,93.7c0-2.2-0.5-4.2-1.5-6
    c3.1-2.2,7.6-4.5,8.8-4.5h1.4c2.8,0,5-2.2,5-5v-0.4c0-4.5-5.1-5.2-5.2-5.3c-2-0.8-3.4-2.7-3.4-5C81.1,65.3,82.6,63.3,84.7,62.6z"/>
</g>

  <path id="lightning" class="lightning" d="M65.2,43.7L67.7,56l3.1,15.9L63.4,56L52.9,33.2l9.9-0.4l-5-27.6l17.3,38L65.2,43.7z"/>

  <animate 
            xlink:href="#left-arm"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
               M6,20.8c0,0,21.3,0,21.3,21.2c0,21.2-20.8,18.4-20.8,41.4c0,22.6,36.7,34.4,52.9-8.9;

                     M20,50.1c0,0,2.8-5.8-6.5,13.3c-12.6,25.9-40.3,64-15,78c20.2,11.2,41-11.5,57.1-54.9;

M-2,140.2c0,0,0,0-4.2,4.4c-5.2,5.5-21.2,30.8-0.2,40.5c27.9,12.8,46.2-59.2,62.3-102.5;

M6,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4C6,146,46.2,124.7,62.4,81.3;

 M10,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4C6,146,46.2,124.7,62.4,81.3;

M6,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4C6,146,46.2,124.7,62.4,81.3;

M-2,140.2c0,0,0,0-4.2,4.4c-5.2,5.5-21.2,30.8-0.2,40.5c27.9,12.8,46.2-59.2,62.3-102.5;

M20,50.1c0,0,2.8-5.8-6.5,13.3c-12.6,25.9-40.3,64-15,78c20.2,11.2,41-11.5,57.1-54.9;

                      M6,20.8c0,0,21.3,0,21.3,21.2c0,21.2-20.8,18.4-20.8,41.4c0,22.6,36.7,34.4,52.9-8.9;


            Z;"/>

  <animate 
            xlink:href="#left-mid-arm"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
               M58.5,99.6c-31.1,25.5-50,28.7-50,50.8c0,15.8,10.2,22.9,16,26.6;

                     M58.6,98.4c-21.2,26-37.6,7-50,25.4c-9.7,14.5,10.2,22.9,16,26.6;

M61.5,106.4c-31.1,25.5-33,56.3-33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;

                                         M64.5,106.4c-31.1,25.5-33,56.3-33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;

M61.5,106.4c-31.1,25.5-33,56.3-33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;                     
                     M58.6,98.4c-21.2,26-37.6,7-50,25.4c-9.7,14.5,10.2,22.9,16,26.6;

                     M58.5,99.6c-31.1,25.5-50,28.7-50,50.8c0,15.8,10.2,22.9,16,26.6;


            Z;"/>

   <animate 
            xlink:href="#right-mid-arm"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
               M69.7,99.6c31.1,25.5,50,28.7,50,50.8c0,15.8-10.2,22.9-16,26.6;

M69.7,98.4c21.2,26,37.6,7,50,25.4c9.7,14.5-10.2,22.9-16,26.6;

M68,106.4c31.1,25.5,33,56.3,33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;

M64,106.4c31.1,25.5,33,56.3,33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;

M68,106.4c31.1,25.5,33,56.3,33,78.4c0,15.8,0,5.1,0,15.8;  
                     M69.7,98.4c21.2,26,37.6,7,50,25.4c9.7,14.5-10.2,22.9-16,26.6;

M69.7,99.6c31.1,25.5,50,28.7,50,50.8c0,15.8-10.2,22.9-16,26.6;


            Z;"/>

  <animate 
            xlink:href="#right-arm"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
               M122,20.8c0,0-21.3,0-21.3,21.2c0,21.2,20.8,18.4,20.8,41.4c0,22.6-36.7,34.4-52.8-8.9;

                     M105.9,50.4c0,0-2.3-3.1,10.4,14c12.7,17,44.3,62.7,22,78.3c-22.7,16-50.5-11.9-66.6-55.2;

 M128,140.2c0,0,0,0,4.2,4.4c5.2,5.5,21.2,30.8,0.2,40.5c-27.9,12.8-46.2-59.2-62.3-102.5;                     
                     M124,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4c0-53.9-40.2-75.2-56.3-118.5;

M120,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4c0-53.9-40.2-75.2-56.3-118.5;

                     M124,216.7c0,0,0-1.3,0-5.4c0-5.7,0-1.7,0-11.4c0-53.9-40.2-75.2-56.3-118.5;
                    M128,140.2c0,0,0,0,4.2,4.4c5.2,5.5,21.2,30.8,0.2,40.5c-27.9,12.8-46.2-59.2-62.3-102.5;

                     M105.9,50.4c0,0-2.3-3.1,10.4,14c12.7,17,44.3,62.7,22,78.3c-22.7,16-50.5-11.9-66.6-55.2;


                     M122,20.8c0,0-21.3,0-21.3,21.2c0,21.2,20.8,18.4,20.8,41.4c0,22.6-36.7,34.4-52.8-8.9;


            Z;"/>

    <animate 
            xlink:href="#right-leg"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
               M68.5,108.9c4,2.5,8.9,8.6,7.2,21.3c-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.2;

M68.5,105.9c4,2.5,7.2,3.5,7.2,16.3c0,2.2-0.4,4-1.2,5.8;

                   M68.5,105.7c4,2.5,7.2,8.5,7.2,21.3c0,2-0.1,3.7-0.4,5.1;

M68.5,105.9c4,2.5,7.2,3.5,7.2,16.3c0,2.2-0.4,4-1.2,5.8;


 M68.5,108.9c4,2.5,8.9,8.6,7.2,21.3c-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.2;


            Z;"/>

      <animate 
            xlink:href="#right-foot"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="
M51.5,156.9c-2.3,3-3.7,6.7-3.7,11.9c0,5.1,1.4,8.8,3.1,11.5;

                     M48,156.9c0,5.9,0,3,0,4.9c0,3.9,0,2.8,0,3.9;

                     M52.5,156.9c0,5.9,0,3,0,4.9c0,3.9,0,2.8,0,3.9;

                     M48,156.9c0,5.9,0,3,0,4.9c0,3.9,0,2.8,0,3.9;

                     M51.5,156.9c-2.3,3-3.7,6.7-3.7,11.9c0,5.1,1.4,8.8,3.1,11.5;
            Z;"/>

        <animate 
            xlink:href="#left-leg"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="

M63.8,107.6c0,0-14.3,0.3-11.6,20.6c2.8,20.8,27.9,19,27.9,40.6c0,14.6-11.2,18-11.2,18;

M63.9,114.4c0,0,3-0.6,10.2,18.5c6,16.1,6,30.2,6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;

M60.9,114.4c0,0,3-0.6,10.2,18.5c6,16.1,6,30.2,6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;

M63.9,114.4c0,0,3-0.6,10.2,18.5c6,16.1,6,30.2,6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;


M63.8,107.6c0,0-14.3,0.3-11.6,20.6c2.8,20.8,27.9,19,27.9,40.6c0,14.6-11.2,18-11.2,18;


            Z;"/>


          <animate 
            xlink:href="#right-leg"
             attributeName="d" 
             dur="1s"
             begin="squid.mouseover"
             end="squid.mouseout"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             values="

 M63.2,107.6c0,0,6.3-0.1,10.3,7.6c1.6,3.1,2.4,6.4,2.3,10.2c-0.1,2.7-0.6,6.1-0.6,6.1;                    

M68.2,107.6c0,0,14.3,0.3,11.6,20.6c-2.8,20.8-27.9,19-27.9,40.6c0,14.6,11.2,18,11.2,18;

M64.7,114.4c0,0-3-0.6-10.2,18.5c-6,16.1-6,30.2-6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;

M68.7,114.4c0,0-3-0.6-10.2,18.5c-6,16.1-6,30.2-6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;

M64.7,114.4c0,0-3-0.6-10.2,18.5c-6,16.1-6,30.2-6,40.2c0,4,0,10.3,0,10.3;


M68.2,107.6c0,0,14.3,0.3,11.6,20.6c-2.8,20.8-27.9,19-27.9,40.6c0,14.6,11.2,18,11.2,18;
                     M63.2,107.6c0,0,6.3-0.1,10.3,7.6c1.6,3.1,2.4,6.4,2.3,10.2c-0.1,2.7-0.6,6.1-0.6,6.1;  

            Z;"/>


  </g>
</svg>
```

Here's my pen - hover it for example.

http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/mOrYBd?editors=1100

Comment: http://codepen.io/ashokkumar01cbe/pen/GNNoVL?editors=1101

Comment: @Ashok That's not very helpful if you don't explain what you changed.

Comment: Does the animation works correctly as you expected @PaulLeBeau?

Comment: In the animation it has been given as mouseover. I changed it to mouse enter.@PaulLeBeau

Comment: @Ashokkumar That's better just, need it to loop forever until mouseout. Also want the animation to finish after mouse out and not just stop if possible.

Comment: @Ashokkumar Here is my new pen http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/mOrYBd but you'll see that there's a glitch now where the animation starts and ends when the mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

Mouseover fires every time you move the mouse.  Try mouseenter instead.

```
begin="squid.mouseenter"
```

Comment: This only works if you remove the end="squid.mouseout" segment, but than the animation never stops... I want the animation to loop while hovered and stop on mouseout

Comment: Here is my new pen codepen.io/alcoven/pen/mOrYBd but you'll see that there's a glitch now where the animation starts and ends when the mouse moves.

Comment: Did you change it? It is not ending when the mouse moves for me.